# Is there a way to export/import attributes, categories, and products in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to export data for:

- attributes
- attribute sets
- categories
- simple products
- configurable products

I don't want to use the admin GUI... I'm lookng for a command line solution.

Perhaps one way to do it is to know which tables I need to manually export and then import?

I've also recently discovered the wonderful n98-magerun tool. Perhaps there is a custom module for this to allow me to accomplish this?